# How to make a trust for the last christmas tree?

Tags: java

```
public class Xmas{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("program.");
        System.out.print("Height: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Height can only be positive.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Levels: ");
            int sz = sc.nextInt();
            if (sz <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Levels can only be positive.");
            }
            else
                for (int s = 0; s < sz; s++) {
                    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                        for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++) { 
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    for(int k=0; k<=2*i; k++) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                    }  
                }
        }               

    }
}
```

I need this for the last tree:
I have to do a 3*3 strut in the middle of the tree.

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
   ***
   ***
   ***
```

I have no idea how to do that. 
please help me and give me a code! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry Viktor but I didn't understand you, could you add some details ? for example are you trying to draw a tree in console ? what do you mean by `last tree` ? what tree ? I don't see any trees in your post :)

Comment: @niceman I suggested an edit to his post, hopefully that will get approved.  In case it doesn't (for some reason), you can look at the question by clicking the edit button to see the source.

Comment: That being said, this is not a very good question. It literally says "give me a code" right there.

Comment: i can't write the figure here. Im new in stackoverflow, can i talk with you in private somewhere where i can show you, what i need to do?

Comment: i just need help guys.

Comment: After the else you need an additional out.println(), where you set the asterisk on a position depending on height. In practice you'll need an additional for-loop with `out.print(" ");` and on the last index of this loop you do `out.print("*");` E.g. on a heigh with 4 youll have a base of 7 asterisks, so you need a loop which prints 3 " " and one "*".

Comment: hmm there is chat but you need 25 reps to use it. anyway don't worry , I once was a banned user, now I have 718 rep

Comment: Ill edit my code below later. Didnt know you need 3 lines with 3 asterisks. Code below just prints one asterisk in the middle. But maybe you can extend it yourself with this base.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is maybe that what you are searching for. The additional loop prints the asterisks depending on the height. Three lines with 3 asterisks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("program.");
    System.out.print("Height: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    if (n <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Height can only be positive.");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Levels: ");
        int sz = sc.nextInt();
        if (sz <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Levels can only be positive.");
        } else {
            for (int s = 0; s < sz; s++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k <= 2 * i; k++) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (j == n - 2) {
                    System.out.println("***");
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: thanks its almost good, now if i do another for loop, it wont work :(

Comment: I edited the code, now you have 3 lines with 3 asterisks.